# Multiple SSL ceritificates

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use multiple certificates(.p12) in multiple thread groups. The following is the set up, 
    ThreadGroup1
     HTTPRequest1
     CSVdataconfig - cert_alias1.csv
     Keystoreconfig - cert1 alias name

```
ThreadGroup2 
 HTTPRequest2   
 CSVdataconfig - cert_alias2.csv    
 Keystoreconfig - cert2 alias name  

ThreadGroup3 
 HTTPRequest3   
 CSVdataconfig - cert_alias3.csv 
 Keystoreconfig - cert3 alias name
```

Have combined all three (.p12) certificates into one keystore(.jks) file using Keystore tool . 
If 'Run Thread Groups consecutively'(in Test Plan) is checked , the script works fine. 
If 'Run Thread Groups consecutively'(in Test Plan) is unchecked , HTTP requests fail intermittently.

PS: I am importing .jks file into SSL Manager prior to test run and providing password on the prompt. Also used keystore parameters in system.properties file.

Comment: Please post the error message. Thanks!

Comment: HTTP -500,'INVALID_AGENT', as it is trying to send the request with other client certificate.